# Load bert model in java

Tags: java, python, named-entity-recognition, bert-language-model

I have bert model for named entity recognition.(config.json, model.bin, vocab.txt).
I can load model and get named entities from text with model in python

```
input_text = "I live in London"
model_dir = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/v1"

print (get_predictions(input_text, model_dir)  )
```

How can i load this model in Java and get named entities